# How to use app logging in flask views, it returns cannot import name logger

Tags: logging, flask

I want to make flask project to large project structure
so I found sample project like following

```
 ~/LargeApp
|-- run.py
|-- config.py
|__ /env             # Virtual Environment
|__ /app             # Our Application Module
     |-- __init__.py
     |-- /module_one
         |-- __init__.py
         |-- views.py
         |-- models.py                
     |__ /templates
         |__ /module_one
             |-- hello.html
     |__ /static
     |__ ..
     |__ .
|__ ..
|__ .
```

I write create_app function in /app/**init**.py

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

    app.logger = my_get_logger_function() # this function set log level, and add handler to logger and return logger
    db.init_app(app)

    from .module_one.views import mod as module_one_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(module_one_blueprint)

    return app
```

and I want to use logger in my /app/module_one/views.py,
following is my views.py file

```
from app import logger
...
@mod.route('/test/', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    logger.info('test')
```

but when i run, i got message "**ImportError: cannot import name 'logger**"

I know it's because I call logger in views.py before app was created

but i really don't know how i fix it and how do i design a my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really the error is due to you have not defined the name `logger` in your module `app`. If you want to use the app logger, you should import the `current_app` from `flask` which is the instance of your app as follows:

```
from flask import current_app
```

Then, in your view, you can use the logger:

```
current_app.logger.info('Your message')
```

Comment: thank you!!! i think i',m real idiot. I found this another page. but i try it to "from app import current_app"... i don't know why i didn't find flask...

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `from flask.logging import logging`
I also had this problem, I don't know why, but I tried it and it worked well.